# Building PostGIS address_standardizer extension formerly known as PAGC address normalizer on Mac?

Tags: postgis-2.2

I have come a long way towards completing the TIGER Geocoder. However, I cannot perform an installation of postgres and postgis that reveals the new PostGIS 2.2.1 address_standardizer extension or any address normalizer extension.

It is clear that I will need to build this from source found in the postgis extras. Since I have rarely succeeded at config-make-install efforts, I know that this critical step will require preparing an accurate and complete list of other libraries that I will also need to config, make and install.

How can I find the correct and complete list of dependencies i need to install on my mac in order to succeed?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the extension is installed:

```
CREATE EXTENSION address_standardizer SCHEMA public VERSION "2.2.2";
```

And turn it on in Tiger:

```
UPDATE tiger.geocode_settings_default SET setting='true' WHERE name='use_pagc_address_parser';
```